# Check a json value against a regexp throws a is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I've a problem with an if statement, where I want to check the value against a regExp. But I get "data[key].name is not a function", how do I go about to fix this issue?

```
document.querySelector('#search').onkeyup = function() {
var searchField = document.querySelector('#search').value;
var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'allCountries.json', true);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var output = '<ul class="searchresult">';
        for(var key in data) {
            if(data[key].name(myExp) != -1 || data[key].code(myExp) != -1) {
                output += '<li>' + data[key].name + ' - ' + data[key].code + 
                '</li>';
            }
        }
        output += '</ul>';
        document.querySelector('#update').innerHTML = output;
    } 
};

request.send();
};
```

Comment: What are those `.name` and `.code` methods? Or, broader, what are you *trying* to do in that if-statement?

Comment: That is the keys from the JSON file, and I want to check the value from the keys against the regExp.

Comment: @user3403590 `something(somethingelse)` means to call `something` as a function. So `data[key].name(myExp)` tries to use `data[key].name` as a function. But it's not a function, it's a string that you want to test with a regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a String matches a RegEx pattern, use the [`String#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/String/match) function:

Change your `if` statement to

```
if (data[key].name.match(myExp) || data[key].code.match(myExp)) {
```

```js
var myExp = new RegExp("something.*[23]", "i");

var data = {a:{name:"something1", code:"somethingElse1"}, b:{name:"something2", code:"somethingElse2"}, c:{name:"something3", code:"somethingElse3"}}
var output = '<ul class="searchresult">';
for (var key in data) {
  if (data[key].name.match(myExp) || data[key].code.match(myExp)) {
    output += '<li>' + data[key].name + ' - ' + data[key].code +
      '</li>';
  }
}
output += '</ul>';
document.querySelector('#update').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="update"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `name` and `code` are strings you should test your regex this way:

```
if(myExp.test(data[key].name) || myExp.test(data[key].code))
```